# Derive a rotation from a 2D rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I have a rotation 2D rotation matrix. I know that this matrix will always ever only be a rotation matrix.

> $$\left[
> \begin{array}{@{}cc}
> \cos a & -\sin a \\
> \sin a & \cos a \\
> \end{array}
> \right]$$

How can I extract the rotation from this matrix?

The less steps, the better, since this will be done on a computer and I don't want it to constantly be doing a lot of computations!

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the rotation"?  Do you mean you want to extract the *angle* of rotation?  Or something different?

Comment: @Muphrid Yes, the angle of rotation. Whatever I plugged in for the rotation a, right?

Comment: If $A$ denotes your matrix, compute $A(1,0)=:(x,y)$. If $x\neq 0$, $\tan a=y/x$. You can take $\arctan$ and get $a$ $mod 2\pi$. If $x=0$, $a$ is either $+\pi/2$ (mod $2\pi$) or $+\pi/2$ (mod $2\pi$), depending whether $a=1$ or $a=-1$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pick any non-zero vector $v$ and compute the angle between $v$ and $Av$, where $A$ is the matrix above.

A simple vector is $e_1 = \binom{1}{0}$, and $Ae_1 = \binom{\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha} = \binom{A_{11}}{A_{21}}$, hence the angle $\alpha$ can be computed from $\text{atan2}(\sin \alpha, \cos \alpha) = \text{atan2}(A_{21}, A_{11}) $. (Note that $\text{atan2}$ usually takes the $y$-component as the first argument.)

Comment: So, basically you're applying the rotation matrix to a temporary vector, in this case a vector pointing up, and then doing the dot product between the rotated temporary vector and the non-rotated temporary vector, thus retrieving the angle? Assuming I got that right (math is far from my strong suite) that sounds fine, though i'm suprised there is not a quicker way

Comment: Just compute $\text{atan2}(A_{21}, A_{11}) $, where $A_{11}$ is the $(1,1)$ element of your matrix, and similarly for $A_{21}$. You can choose any vector you want, but the choice above makes the resulting computation particularly straightforward. Also, do use $\text{atan2}$ if available, using $\text{atan}$ directly involves checking a number of special cases.

Comment: I assumed that you have an explicit representation of the matrix $A$, if not, then compute $A \binom{1}{0}$ to obtain $\binom{A_{11}}{A_{21}}$.

Comment: You need to be careful using the dot product, as it is insensitive to sign, and the calculation is sensitive to noise if the angle is small (because $\cos'(0) = 0$).

Comment: Just a note, the first column of the rotation matrix already gives you $\cos\theta$ & $\sin\theta$, there is no need to apply the rotation to any vectors. Put another way, the first column vector in the rotation matrix tells you where $\hat\imath$ will end up after the rotation. So just call $atan2$ on the entries in the first column of the rotation matrix, reversing the order if needed to put the $y$ component first.